# Is by JOOQ generated api depended from DBMS?

Tags: mysql, oracle, hsqldb, jooq

I have generated the API with Jooq from local HSQLDB (DBMS). And the tests runs ok.
But I get exceptions when trying to run the test with another DBMS like MySQL.
Also, I have seen that the generated API attributes by MySQL are case sensitiv and by HSQLDB not.

My question: is it possible to develope with Jooq local with HSQLDB and run the live system with Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: You should never develop on a DBMS that is different from your production DBMS. There are much more (subtle) differences than just the syntax, which you simply cannot account for.

Comment: I haven' oracle local on my mashine, and I dont think so. Hibernate make this with dialect management.

Comment: It's a lot more than just the "dialect" (and I don't see the point in using JOOQ when you already us an ORM like Hibernate)

Comment: I think it's valid to use jOOQ and not Hibernate. I also think it's valid to use multiple databases (for whatever reason).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: While I generally agree with you (I'd *prefer* to have only a single database type in my architecture), I don't think it's entirely wrong to mix things, if you're not tightly coupling your application to your database. Or what kinds of features (that one *cannot* account for) did you have in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use jOOQ with several databases. The most "daring" users known to me from the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jooq-user) use jOOQ with at least five different (productive!) database systems (among which: Oracle, SQL Server, Sybase).

Note though, that jOOQ will only abstract your database to a certain extent. As soon as you're using vendor-specific features, you may run into problems. jOOQ will not *guarantee*, that all the rendered SQL will work on all your databases. It will just *simplify* the standardisation task.

Since you're trying to combine HSQLDB and Oracle, problematic features include (among many others):

- Oracle's different implementation of the `DATE` data type
- Oracle's analytical functions
- Oracle's inferior `VARCHAR` / `VARCHAR2` data types
- Oracle's extended `FOR UPDATE` syntax
- Oracle's extended `MERGE` syntax
- Oracle's strongly typed, named array types - as opposed to HSQLDB's array types
- Oracle's lack of explicit `INTEGER` data types (in particular for stored procedures)
- Oracle's support for packages and UDTs
- Oracle's lack of empty string support (`''` and `NULL` are the same)
- Oracle's partitioned outer join
- Oracle's `PIVOT` / `UNPIVOT` clauses

Of course, incompatibilities remain also when a feature is not supported explicitly by jOOQ. These include (among many others):

- Oracle's AQ
- Oracle's `MODEL` clause

Also, you're responsible yourself for

- Maintaining equivalent meta data in all databases (if in doubt, use case-sensitive table / column names, i.e. by writing `CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE"...` (Oracle, HSQLDB) or `` CREATE TABLE `MY_TABLE`... `` (MySQL)
- Maintaining equivalent data types and data in all databases

On the other hand, you can safely use jOOQ and jOOQ's SQL abstraction capabilities for

- Most functions
- Most SQL clauses, including complex nested SQL

For more information, please consider the [`org.jooq.Support`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/class-use/Support.html) Javadoc. This annotation is used on all API elements to document whether jOOQ is capable of simulating the underlying SQL clause / function in relevant dialects.

Apart from that, if your only problem is the case-sensitivity of table names, consider telling jOOQ not to quote names through jOOQ's Settings:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/executor/custom-settings/

An example:

```java
// This DSLContext will not render quoted table / column names:
Settings settings = new Settings().withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS);
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, dialect, settings);
```

Comment: Not to mention Oracle's different take on OFFSET & LIMIT.

Comment: @onepotato: This is handled pretty well by jOOQ, rendering nested selects and `ROWNUM` filtering transparently to the user. Details can be seen here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/

Comment: There's a lot more SQL standardisation going on in jOOQ. Here are a couple of fun examples: http://blog.jooq.org/2013/05/03/sql-query-transformation-fun-predicates-with-row-value-expressions, http://blog.jooq.org/2013/01/07/simulating-the-sql-standard, http://blog.jooq.org/2012/12/26/row-value-expressions-and-the-between-predicate, http://blog.jooq.org/2012/09/21/the-is-distinct-from-predicate, and many more...

Comment: I'm using jooq now. I no longer need to determine if the connection source is HSQLDB or ORACLE since `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` are handled the same way. This is a big improvement to my application. I wish I could upvote this thread many times.

Comment: @onepotato: Well, you can still spread the word about jOOQ :-)